# backbone.js: how would i handle sending login data from client to server with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Being relatively new to backbone.js, I've created several small tests from a simple model and collection displayed on a page, to the few dollars worth [peepcode screencast](http://peepcode.com/products/backbone-js) about backbone (which is very good actually)

but, I still see everything directly referenced, as:
there is a certain model called User, then you have a view that prints how that user model looks.

lets say a user opens the site, sees a login form, after the submit click, where do I store / how do I handle the connection to the server, for validation and testing if the username / password were correct?

would I need to save things like that in a separate model?

I think I'm still thinking too mutch about really well defined entities in my app, a user, who has contacts. and I get the feeling that I will need to create models for more than just these defined entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking correctly.  Login is just a method performed on behalf of the user entity.  For me, what seems best is to just append a login method to your user model.  It will check this.get('username') and this.get('password') and make an ajax request for validation.

This method should take in two callbacks,  loginSuccess and loginError(error).  When the login request comes back OK you should set some property on the user model: this.set({ authenticated: true })

Your views could then userModel.bind('change:authenticated', this.update); and update themselves appropriately.

Comment: So the model knows that it's "authenticated" but I can set that same value on the model via the Firebug or Chrome console. You can't trust that from the server side. There must be something more than that that is used to re-validate the user's identity with each request made from client to server.

Comment: Absolutely there is more to it than what I mentioned, but his questions seemed more in line with the backbone way of handling authentication, not necessarily the details of security.  Ideally his login method would also append a token value to be appended to requests by overloading backbone.sync

Comment: ah my question was already asked above, anyway, the backbone way of login seems ok, but then in combination with some sort of token like described in the other post.  thanks both

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's certainly not the only way to do this, but we're using CAS to handle authentication on the back end. So the browser gets a cookie that says, "Hey, you're logged in," that is sent back with all of the REST queries later. The actual calls to the back end don't really worry about authenticated or not authenticated in all their communication, they just rely on that cookie going with every request and a second piece of code verifying that the user is valid outside of everything else. It seems to work well.

I would think you're going to need something similar. Some form of token given from the server to the client that goes with each request (hopefully over HTTPS for security's sake) that is used to verify that the server has successfully authenticated that user. There's absolutely nothing that the client can use to accomplish the same thing short of sending user name and password with each request to the back end.